# Geom_area com cores diferentes de preechimento

Tags: r, ggplot2

Eu tenho um `DF` com 4 colunas: `data`, `original`, `previsto` e `change`. A variável `change` indica se os valores da série `original` são positivos ou negativos, para plotar no gráfico em verde e vermelho, respectivamente. Tentei utilizar o `geom_area`, mas o gráfico fica dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como corrigir esse problema de ter a linha verde onde era para ter somente a vermelha e vice-versa?

Meu código:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  filter(variaveis == c("diferenca.em.pontos")) %>%
  mutate(change = ifelse(value > 0, "positive", "negative")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Período, y = value, fill = change)) +
  geom_area() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

Meu `dput`:

```
data <- structure(list(Período = structure(c(13453, 13483, 13514, 13545, 
13573, 13604, 13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 13787, 13818, 
13848, 13879, 13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 14061, 14092, 
14123, 14153, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 16071), class = "Date"), 
    variaveis = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Brasil", "Brasil.predicted", 
    "Brasil.nivel", "Brasil.predicted.nivel", "diferenca.em.pontos"
    ), class = "factor"), value = c(28.5307986472031, 22.8246389177625, 
    16.3033135126875, 6.52132540507499, 4.07582837817188, -12.2274851345156, 
    -10.5971537832469, -8.96682243197813, -6.521325405075, -4.89099405380624, 
    -11.4123194588812, -20.3791418908594, -8.96682243197812, 
    -10.5971537832469, -9.7819881076125, -6.521325405075, 0, 
    -8.15165675634375, -27.7156329715687, -43.2037808086219, 
    -34.2369583766437, -26.9004672959344, -17.9336448639562, 
    -38.3127867548156, -18.7488105395906, -25.2701359446656, 
    -21.1943075664937, -14.6729821614187, -8.15165675634375, 
    0.815165675634374), change = c("positive", "positive", "positive", 
    "positive", "positive", "negative", "negative", "negative", 
    "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", 
    "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", 
    "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", 
    "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", 
    "negative", "positive")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta solução é inteiramente baseada em [este post da usuária Yarnabrina](https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotting-negative-and-positive-laues/29765/10) do RStudio que por sua vez é baseada, com créditos, numa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137211/8245406) do usuário @Henrik do StackOveflow em Inglês.

O princípio é muito simples, encontrar os pontos de intersecção com o eixo dos x por interpolação linear. Para isso usam-se regressões lineares só com dois pontos de cada vez e fica-se com os resultados se os pontos mudarem de sinal. Note-se ainda que as regressões invertem as variáveis dos eixos, como queremos as interseções `x`, as regressões são `x ~ y`.

```
library(ggplot2)

data$grp <- "orig"

new_df <- do.call(rbind,
                  lapply(1:(nrow(data) -1), FUN = function(i) {
                    fit <- lm(Período ~ value, data = data[i:(i + 1),])
                    if (fit$qr$rank < 2) return(NULL)
                    zero <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(value = 0))
                    if(data$Período[i] < zero & zero < data$Período[i + 1]){
                      return(data.frame(Período = zero, value = 0))
                    } else {
                      return(NULL)
                    }
                  }))

new_df$grp <- "new"
new_df$Período <- as.Date(new_df$Período, origin = "1970-01-01")
df_mod <- rbind(data[c(1,3,5)], new_df)

ggplot(df_mod, aes(x = Período, y = value)) +
  geom_area(data = subset(df_mod, value <= 0), fill = "red") +
  geom_area(data = subset(df_mod, value >= 0), fill = "blue") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma solução mais simples para o gráfico, depois de processados os dados, com o mesmo resultado, será a seguinte.

```
ggplot(df_mod, aes(x = Período, y = value, fill = value >= 0)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela solução! Mas ao rodar o código para gerar o ```new_df```, retornou o erro ```Error in 1:(nrow(data) - 1) : argumento de comprimento zero```.

Comment: @AlexandreSanches O que é que `nrow(data)` dá?

Comment: Retorna 825 linhas.

Comment: @AlexandreSanches Voltei a rodar o código, numa sessão R nova, e não dá erro. `1:(nrow(data) - 1)` dá um vetor de comprimento 824?

Comment: Consegui o resultado pretendido adicionando ```tidyr::complete(change, Período, fill = list(value = 0)) %>%```.

Answer (score 1):

Semelhante à [resposta do Rui Barradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467756/117168), mas primeiro detectando as linhas seguidas de intersecção e depois determinando o valor do eixo x usando interpolação linear.

Estou usando *geom_ribbon* ao invés de *geom_area* pois isso permite usar interceptos diferentes (*area* é um caso especial de *ribbon* em que o ponto de origem em y é pré definido como 0). Também estou usando dados simulados para ter mais variações e assim exibir melhor o resultado final.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Dados simulados
set.seed(657)
data <- data.frame(
  Período = as.Date(sample(13453:16071, 50), origin = "1970-01-01"),
  value = rnorm(50, 2, 2))

# Garante que os dados estão ordenados
data <- data[order(data$Período), ]

# Define o intercepto (no caso dos seus dados, só usar 0):
intercept <- mean(data$value)

# Acha os pontos que cruzam o inrecepto e calcula os valores de x correspondentes:
r <- ifelse(data$value < intercept, 0, 1)
ind <- na.exclude((1:nrow(data))[r != c(r[-1], NA)])
npx <- sapply(ind, function(i) approx(data$value[i:(i+1)], data$Período[i:(i+1)], intercept)$y)

# Novo conjunto de dados com os pontos em que há mudança:
newdata <- rbind(data[c("Período", "value")],
                 data.frame(Período = as.Date(npx, origin = "1970-01-01"),
                            value = intercept))
newdata$value.pos <- ifelse(newdata$value >= intercept, newdata$value, intercept)
newdata$value.neg <- ifelse(newdata$value <= intercept, newdata$value, intercept)

ggplot(newdata, aes(Período, value)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = intercept, ymax = value.pos), fill = "blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = value.neg, ymax = intercept), fill = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = intercept)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]