# ggplot: geom_area - erro com aes(fill)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho os seguintes dados e gostaria de criar um gráfico com o `ggplot2::geom_area()` com cores diferentes para os valores positivos e negativos. No entanto, estou obtendo um erro e não estou conseguindo resolve-lo. Alguém poderia ajudar?

```
dados <- structure(list(year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), month = structure(1:12, .Label = c("January", 
"February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November", "December"), class = "factor"), 
    diff = c(167916.47, 58945.82, 432269.2, 532863.2, -434494, 
    -493142.3, -50919.75, -207215.3, -278524.84, -77664.68, 161101.79, 
    144261.69), signal = c("pos", "pos", "pos", "pos", "neg", 
    "neg", "neg", "neg", "neg", "neg", "pos", "pos")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Quando 'ploto' os dados sem o `geom_area(aes(fill = signal))`, o gráfico sai correto:

[image]

No entato, quando uso o argumento `fill` para tentar preencher positivos e negativos com cores diferentes

```
dados %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = diff, 
             group = 1))+
  geom_area(aes(fill = signal))
```

obtenho o seguinte erro: `Erro: Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon`.

Alguém sabia dizer onde está o erro? Tentei com dados diferentes desses (com variável contínua no eixo X) e consegui, mas com esses não. Obrigado.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Geom\_area com cores diferentes de preechimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/467729/geom-area-com-cores-diferentes-de-preechimento)

Comment: é exatamente isso que quero, cheguei a ver essa pergunta/resposta, mas não consegui transpassar a lógica para os meus dados. vou tentar/estudar mais um pouco. valeu!

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa do parâmetro *group* quando usar fatores no gráfico para que o geom_area não interprete cada fator como um grupo diferente.
A doc neste [link](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html) tem um exemplo com geom_line.

Para obter o efeito que vc deseja, é necessário dividir os dados em grupos, conforme explicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883154/how-do-i-fill-a-geom-area-plot-using-ggplot).

No seu caso, você tem apenas 1 grupo, o que facilita a situação. Mas este gráfico pode ficar complicado se você tivesse vários grupos com valores positivos e negativos alternados. Há uma boa discussão a respeito nesta [thread](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2802).

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, tentei reproduzir aqui, a partir dos meus dados, e de primeira não saiu. vou tentar descobrir onde está o erro.